# What could be the reason for empty jpg file generated from plsql script when extracting more than one record

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am having this script in plsql where am trying to extract images to a directory where i have like 100 records in a database, the code is extracting all the records but they are blank files, what could be the issue.

Below is the block of code, Please assist.

```
--create or replace directory my_dir as '/export/home/Desktop/Pic';

DECLARE

v_dir varchar2(10):='MY_DIR';
t_blob BLOB;
t_len NUMBER;
t_file_name VARCHAR2(100);
t_output UTL_FILE.file_type;
t_TotalSize number;
t_position number := 1;
t_chucklen NUMBER := 4096;
t_chuck raw(4096);
t_remain number;

BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..100 LOOP


SELECT DBMS_LOB.getlength (IMAGE), brid ||'P.jpg'
    INTO t_TotalSize, t_file_name FROM Photo WHERE IMAGEID=i;

IF (t_file_name IS NOT NULL) THEN


dbms_output.put_line('Got: ' || t_file_name);

t_remain := t_TotalSize;
t_output := UTL_FILE.fopen (v_dir, t_file_name, 'WB', 32760);

SELECT IMAGE INTO t_blob FROM Photo WHERE IMAGEID=i;

WHILE t_position < t_TotalSize LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.READ (t_blob, t_chucklen, t_position, t_chuck);
    UTL_FILE.put_raw (t_output, t_chuck);
    UTL_FILE.fflush (t_output);
    t_position := t_position + t_chucklen;
    t_remain := t_remain - t_chucklen;
    IF t_remain < 4096
    THEN
        t_chucklen := t_remain;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
END IF;
END LOOP;
UTL_FILE.fclose (t_output);
END;
```

Comment: Hi, I create a table with a BLOB column, inserted a photo in it and called your code and it **WORKS**, so maybe you have a problem somewhere else(may be Table itself or may be insertion process)

Comment: Thanks for response, However when i call above code for only one record it works fine, the challenge is when the table has more than one record and i want to extract all of them.

Comment: set **t_position := 0** inside loop

Comment: I have set it to 0 but now am getting the following error `ORA-21560: argument 2 is null, invalid, or out of range
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1056
ORA-06512: at line 34`

Comment: Sorry set it to 1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to move UTL_FILE.fclose (t_output); before the end if:

```
END LOOP;
UTL_FILE.fclose (t_output);
END IF;
END LOOP;
```